# Oracle APEX - Set Page to Read Only based on App User

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, oracle-apex

I am currently trying to make a page read only if the user logged in is an administrator.

My login table has an attribute "login_type" which is either "U" for regular user and "A" for admin. I am attempting to use a "EXISTS" condition type on my page with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM login
WHERE
(
    (SELECT login_type FROM login WHERE upper(login_username) =  upper(:APP_USER)) = 'A'
)
```

In theory, this should ensure that anyone logged in, where their user login_type is 'A' should have read only fields on the page. This isn't the case, and I'm struggling to use the read only conditions all together.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

APEX 5

I set:

Read Only Type condition for page: Rows returned

SQL Query:

```
SELECT 1
  FROM login
 WHERE upper(login_username) = upper(:APP_USER)
   AND login_type = 'A'
```

It's worked

Comment: Didn't work for me. Fields are still editable as admin.

Comment: You can try login twice to my application: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54028:4 . There are two users: USER and ADM in LOGIN table Both passwor are: qazwsx. As ADM you can also look at application (page 4 and edit it).